Google Cloud Function trigger doesn't have the correct permissions but Grant All throws an error Invalid service account (undefined)
I have deployed a Google Cloud function and am trying to set up a Cloud Firestore trigger for it.
The problem I'm facing is that when I select Cloud Firestore from the list of triggers, I get a warning saying:
Service account(s) might not have enough permissions to deploy the function with selected trigger. To mitigate potential errors, you can grant them the following roles:
roles/eventarc.eventReceiver to
I then click Grant All but instead of adding the required permissions to the Service Account, it throws an error.

Invalid service account (undefined).

I can go through the rest of the process but when I try to deploy it again with the new settings, nothing happens. It just gives me a toast saying it's updating the function but then times out.
I have tried adding all of the required permissions to all of the Service Accounts and they don't make any difference.

Have you solved this ?
